# Import (imp) not showing final report stats/results

Tags: oracle-10g, import

I'm trying to execute an import of a dmp file an not obtaining the final results of the import. It's really weird because i obtained really big files (nohup.out and imp_xxx.log) with the following content :

```
Column 98 1
Column 99
Column 100
Column 101 0
Column 102 0
Column 103
Column 104
Column 105
Column 106 0
Column 107 0
```

Expected:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Export file created by EXPORT:V10.02.01 via conventional path
import done in WE8ISO8859P15 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing CPEDF33's objects into CPEDF33
. . importing table                 "x"            0 rows imported
. . importing table                 "x1"           0 rows imported
. . importing table                 "x2"           0 rows imported
. . importing table                 "x3"     2599617 rows imported
. . importing table                 "x4"     2244766 rows imported
. . importing table                 "x5"     1561223 rows imported
. . importing table                 "xx5"         20 rows imported
. . importing table                 "xx4"    1931263 rows imported
. . importing table                 "xx3"       2167 rows imported
. . importing table                 "xx2"    4044280 rows imported
. . importing table                 "xx1"    4126340 rows imported
. . importing table                 "x8"        2453 rows imported
. . importing table                 "x7"           0 rows imported
```

Imp command:

```
nohup imp MINE/Hi2013* file=H_FULL_20140212.dmp log=imp_H__FULL_20140212.log FROMUSER=MINE TOUSER=MINE STATISTICS=NONE ROWS=Y IGNORE=Y &
```

Comment: Are you sure it's running the Oracle import program, and not something else? What does `which imp` tell you (assuming you're not on Windows)?

Comment: which imp tell me the following folder : /oracle/ora_10.2.0/bin/imp . Operating systems AIX (unix).

Comment: I'm wondering if the "*" character in your password has done anything, as it's not escaped

Comment: No problem when i did the exp. And data was imported.

Comment: Thanks, Phil, i changed * in password and now works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the unescaped `*` character in your password is causing problems in the shell.

Escape it and you should be ok.

Comment: Yes, i changed it with a # character a now works fine. Thanks.